# 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv

After following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) tutorial to install opencv on my raspberry pi, I was greeted with this error when I run a face recognition code:

> File "03_face_recognition.py", line 15, in 
>       recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
>   AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Like many articles, I tried

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

as well as updating `opencv-python` and `contrib` but none worked for me. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I fixed it by installing cv2 directly on my RPi rather than on a virtual environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pip uninstall opencv-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python

if you are still getting access denied error while installing opencv-contrib-python use below statement

pip install opencv-contrib-python --user